# proper way to use a WCF service?

Tags: c#, wcf

I followed this guide from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) to host a simple WCF service.

But what is the proper way on the client side to use it?

Comment: Just go on using the service, and you will learn the proper way with more implementation only..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most used options are:

- [Generate proxy with Visual Studio or use `svcutil`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691.aspx). This means that it is autogenerated for you, so it's very easy to use and mostly used if the client to your service is external to the system. But as it's generated code, you loose some control.
- Use [ChannelFactory](http://philmunro.wordpress.com/2012/02/15/creating-a-wcf-service-proxy-with-channelfactory/) if the client is tightly bound to the service. I like this method the most because you are working with interfaces directly. In most cases I provide a **[service agent](http://ludwigstuyck.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/a-reference-architecture-part-6/)** that abstracts the use of the service, so that the client doesn't have to worry about it. In this service agent you can also put additional concerns like caching and logging.

Comment: Additionally to your answer don't forget you lose some performance with `ChannelFactory` because the proxy is generated dynamically at runtime :)

Comment: Can you explain? Svcutil generates a class that also uses ChannelFactory?

Comment: Thanks! I'll use the ChannelFactory way from the article you linked.

Answer (score 3):

You can continue your learning path on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730825.aspx).

There are several options:

1. Use **svcutil** to generate the client
2. Use **add service reference** in VS solution context menu
3. Create client on your own (not recommended for
   beginners)

*Note: The first 2 options requires already running service.*

Comment: NO 2 is really convenient, but at the cost of hiding essentials you should know about

Comment: Yes, in fact it is just a GUI wrapper for svcutil.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I prefer to work with WCF service by creating `ChannelFactory<T>` and then creating a channel for communication with it.

Example:

```
ChannelFactory<IProcessor> factory = null;

try
{
    var netTcpBinding = new NetTcpBinding("netTcpBinding_BigPackets");

    factory = new ChannelFactory<IProcessor>(netTcpBinding);

    var processor = factory.CreateChannel(processorAddress);
    var result = processor.Process(request);

    return result;
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
    if (factory != null)
    {
        factory.Abort();
        factory = null;
    }

    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (factory != null)
    {
        factory.Close();
    }
}
```

Good example can be found in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms576132.aspx

Also I would advise you to refer WCF samples from IDesign page: http://idesign.net/Downloads

Answer (score 1):

Add a service reference to your client project and select **Discover/Services in solution**. Then select your service and you'll be able to access all your services methods by writing this kind of code :

```
 using(var myClient = new YourServiceReference.YourService())
 {
   myClient.MyMethod()...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is nice example about usage of WCF services  http://wcfbyexample.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You use it using C# code by extracting the WCF XML from it or use WCF Test Client. Go to Visual Studio and add "Service Reference" using the WCF URL to add the service and it will generate the service code for you.